# How to send text from Excel to Word where one word (cell) is bold?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a spreadsheet with 28 columns of data.  Depending on which columns have a data a sentence is created via the use of if statements.  Once the sentence is created it gets sent to a Word doc.  The data in two of the cells needs to be formatted, column A cells need to be bold and underlined and the other simply underlined, when it is output to Word.  These cells are not formatted in Excel (although if it would make it easier I can change that).  Excel is just holding the data since it is being presented to others via Word where it needs to have the formatting for the reader's benefit.  I know how to get the data to output to Word, but since this is the first time I've done this I don't know how to pass along the formatting.  I'm thinking maybe via Paste Special, but again I don't know how to do that.  Below is the applicable portion of my code.

A string called strLineofText is built up with the data in the cells.  As cell A and cell I are added to the string they need to be formatted with cell A data being bold and underlined.  I only include the portion below that applies to cell A.

```
Const strSHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"

Dim strLineOfText As String       
Dim blnNewApp As Boolean
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim j As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If wordApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    blnNewApp = True
End If

Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSHEET_NAME)
    For j = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        strLineOfText = .Cells(j, "A").Text & ", enlisted " & .Cells(j, "B") & ", served " & .Cells(j, "C") & ", " & .Cells(j, "D") & ", " & .Cells(j, "E")

        wordApp.Selection.TypeText strLineOfText
        wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    Next j
End With

wordApp.Visible = True
AppActivate wordApp.Caption
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not break up the string and toggle formatting between portions?
Here's your code, adjusted:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSHEET_NAME)
    For j = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        wordApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
        wordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = True

        wordApp.Selection.TypeText .Cells(j, "A").Text

        wordApp.Selection.Font.Bold = False
        wordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = False

        wordApp.Selection.TypeText ", enlisted " & .Cells(j, "B") & ", served " & .Cells(j, "C") & ", " & .Cells(j, "D") & ", " & .Cells(j, "E")

    Next j
End With
```

Comment: this does work, but, strangely, the `wordApp.Selection.TypeText ", enlisted " & .Cells(j, "B") & ", served "`....part causes an error unless I remove wordApp.Selection.Type.  I don't understand how it's happening but the formatted data in A is being pre-appended to the string when it outputs.

Comment: @frankbean That was a quick and dirty edit, so it's very possible I didn't format it correctly, but I'm also confused by what you're describing, because I don't think that should be working as described.

Comment: to explain this would be lengthy. The end result is I'm abstracting military pension info from a database which includes soldier's names, service dates, wife's name, when and where marriage took place etc. etc. The soldiers didn't always marry and even when they did the other data isn't always known. A sentence (strLineOfText) describing the life events is created with the soldier name in bold/underline and the wife's name merely underlined. This gets passed to Word. Passing that data usually only passes the raw characters so I was asking how to pass with the formatting.

Comment: @frankbean Sorry, what I wrote might have been confusing. I actually sensed what you were doing with your program from the few key words - it's probably a project that I'd be interested in learning more about. What I meant is that your first comment said that my answer worked if you "remove `wordApp.Selection.Type`" from the line of code. That specific description led me to think that the remaining code would say `Type "some string"` - which I didn't think should be able to function as a stand-alone line. I'm sure the overall program is driving at what you need. Clear as mud?

Answer (score 1):

In general, for figuring stuff like this out, using the Macro Recorder in Excel will give you a basic chunk of code which you can then clean up and streamline.

Let's suppose you have this text in Cell "A1":

```
This is a test of bold face.
```

and you want to higlight the word "test" in bold face.  This code is a slightly cleaned up version of that generated by the Macro Recorder:

```
With Range("A1").Characters(Start:=11, Length:=4).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
```

In reality, you could leave out everything other than the ".FontStyle = Bold" option, but I wanted to include those so you can see that it's possible to control almost any attribute of the text formatting with this technique.

Once you format the text, you can cut and paste to Word easily enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I probably didn't myself clear enough.  What I'm doing is actually rather convoluted to explain.  Using the sentence you supplied above, my cells might have the values "This" in A1 "test" in B1 and "bold face" in C1.  I construct a sentence, and store it in strLineOfText, from A1-C1.  I know how to programmatically imbue formatting in Excel and I'm not simply cutting and pasting to Word.  I'm passing the string strLineOfText to Word.  There will be between 1 to 4 formatted words in strLineOfText that must keep the formatting when I pass them to Word via vba.